Proofs: numbered rows with vertical lines
The goal is to typeset the proofs for exercises in natural deduction.
Here is an example of a proof from the book:

Each row is numbered and consists of a formula and a comment. Also some formulas are eliminated from the proof which is marked by a vertical line on the left.
Here is what I did:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{\setcounter{equation}{0}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Proove the inference:\\
$p \supset r \vdash (p \land r) \supset r$

\begin{align}
  p \supset r & - \text{пос.}\\
  p \land r   & - \text{пос.}\\
  \neg r      & - \text{пос.}\\
  p           & - \land _\text{и} \text{(2)}\\
  r           & - \land _\text{и} \text{(2)}\\
  \neg \neg r & - \neg _\text{в} \text{(5, 3)}\\
\end{align}
\end{document}


I tried the array environment for the lines on the left, but then the numbers disappear.

which book? a number of packages exist which are tailored to the layout used by specific books, so it is generally best to start by establishing whether a package can be found for the book you're using. if not, there may be a package which supports a similar style or can be modified to do so. failing all that, there are some generic approaches to fall back on. but the name of the book is the starting point, unless the introduction tells you it uses a named style. (for example, it might say that it uses 'fitch' or 'lemmon' style because those names have become standard).

see https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/. Peter Smith's site is the place to start looking for LaTeX support for logic - far superior to ctan because so many logicians fail to send their packages to ctan. (i.e. this is not at all a criticism of ctan.) do you really need non-aligned justifications on the right? that's highly unusual.

probably best to adapt one of the fitch packages if there isn't a dedicated style.

@cfr "which book?" - this is a Russian book called "Introduction into Logics" by Markin Bocharov, Moscow State University.

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fitch

@mbert it looks more complicated to hack that one than lplfitch ;).

You could adapt one of the existing Fitch styles. I've used lplfitch because it is actually on CTAN and you probably have it installed already.
I'm not sure which of the differences between the layouts in your two images are intentional and which are not (except those explicitly marked as things you want to change). So I've taken the first image as the target.
The code below demonstrates three options. The first is to use \fitchprf{}{} directly, with a small modification to automate line numbering. If you do this, you need to reset the counter between proofs.
The second and third use a simple wrapper \mbproof[<formula>]{<proof>}, which sets the proof flushed left, or \mbproof*[<formula>]{<proof>}, which centres it. <formula> is the claim to be proved by <proof>.
The wrapper otherwise works exactly as \fitchprf does and you should use the package's macros to input the lines of the proof. The main things to know are that

\pline[<line no.>]{<formula>}[<justification>] sets a proof line. I've modified this so that omitting the first argument causes an automatic number to be used rather than none at all. <justification> is best given using the macros provided by the package, but you don't have to do this and they would all need redefining for your system. I've demonstrated how to do this below, but I've only done it for the justifications my example needed.
\subproof{<assumption>}{<subproof>} works just like \fitchprf{<assumption>}{<proof>}. Essentially, it nests a proof in the way required for this kind of proof layout.
\formula{<formula>} typesets a formula, <formula> in the package's style.


\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/725236/
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lplfitch}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{\setcounter{equation}{0}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*\lif{\supset}
\renewcommand*\lifi[1]{\intro{\lif}, #1}
\renewcommand*\lande[1]{\elim{\land}, #1}
\renewcommand*\intro[1]{--- \formula{#1_\text{в}}}
\renewcommand*\elim[1]{--- \formula{#1_\text{и}}}
\newcommand*\ass{--- пос.}
\newcounter{plinecount}
\AddToHook{cmd/fitchprf/before}{%
  \def\cline#1{\relax}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand \mbproof {so+m+m}{%
  \setcounter{plinecount}{0}%
  \IfValueTF {#2}
  {%
    \def\tmpformula{\formula{#2}}%
  }{%
    \let\tmpformula\relax}%
  \IfBooleanTF {#1}
  {%
    \begin{center}\tmpformula\\\fitchprf{#3}{#4}\end{center}%
  }{%
    \begin{flushleft}\tmpformula\\\fitchprf{#3}{#4}\end{flushleft}%
  }%
}
\makeatletter
\def\pline{\@ifnextchar[\@plinenum{\@plinenum[\refstepcounter{plinecount}\theplinecount.]}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Prove the inference:

$p \lif r \vdash (p \land r) \lif r$

\fitchprf{%
  \pline{p \lif r}[\ass]
}{%
  \subproof{%
    \pline{p \land r}[\ass]\label{ass:p-r}
  }{%
    \pline{p}[\lande{2}]\\
    \pline{r}[\lande{2}]
  }
  \pline{(p \land r) \lif r}[\lifi{2--4}]
}

\mbproof[p \lif r \vdash (p \land r) \lif r]
{%
  \pline{p \lif r}[\ass]
}{%
  \subproof{%
    \pline{p \land r}[\ass]\label{ass:p-r}
  }{%
    \pline{p}[\lande{2}]\\
    \pline{r}[\lande{2}]
  }
  \pline{(p \land r) \lif r}[\lifi{2--4}]
}

\mbproof*[p \lif r \vdash (p \land r) \lif r]
{%
  \pline{p \lif r}[\ass]
}{%
  \subproof{%
    \pline{p \land r}[\ass]\label{ass:p-r}
  }{%
    \pline{p}[\lande{2}]\\
    \pline{r}[\lande{2}]
  }
  \pline{(p \land r) \lif r}[\lifi{2--4}]
}

\end{document}

Off-topic: your proof seems unnecessarily complicated.

Thanks a lot. Is it possible to allow adding lines into the proof after the last hypothesis scope, so they were not inside vertical lines, like the initial formula inside mbproof is, but with line number? It will be the last formula of the proof.

Or maybe ask it as another question?

@user4035 maybe another question with an example would be best, since lplfitch always constructs the scope line, so you need either a further modification or an alternative approach. it would help to link this question/answer in your new one, but it's probably not something I can respond to effectively in a comment :).

@user4035 if you post a link in a comment here, I'll try to have a look, but you may also get the benefit other people looking.

Ok, I did it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/725529/modify-lplfitch-proof-style Is it ok to ask this?
