Modify lplfitch proof style
I this answer cfr gave macros for typesetting the proofs modifying lplfitch style.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lplfitch}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{\setcounter{equation}{0}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*\lif{\supset}
\renewcommand*\lifi[1]{\intro{\lif}, #1}
\renewcommand*\lande[1]{\elim{\land}, #1}
\renewcommand*\intro[1]{--- \formula{#1_\text{в}}}
\renewcommand*\elim[1]{--- \formula{#1_\text{и}}}
\newcommand*\ass{--- пос.}
\newcounter{plinecount}
\AddToHook{cmd/fitchprf/before}{%
  \def\cline#1{\relax}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand \mbproof {so+m+m}{%
  \setcounter{plinecount}{0}%
  \IfValueTF {#2}
  {%
    \def\tmpformula{\formula{#2}}%
  }{%
    \let\tmpformula\relax}%
  \IfBooleanTF {#1}
  {%
    \begin{center}\tmpformula\\\fitchprf{#3}{#4}\end{center}%
  }{%
    \begin{flushleft}\tmpformula\\\fitchprf{#3}{#4}\end{flushleft}%
  }%
}
\makeatletter
\def\pline{\@ifnextchar[\@plinenum{\@plinenum[\refstepcounter{plinecount}\theplinecount.]}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\mbproof[\vdash (p \land (q \lor r)) \lif ((p \land q) \lor (p \land r))]
{
  \pline{(p \land (q \lor r))}[\ass]
}
{
  \subproof{
    \pline{\neg ((p \land q) \lor (p \land r))}[\ass]
  }
  {
    \pline{p}[\lande{1}]\\
    \pline{(\neg (p \lor q)) \land (\neg (p \lor r)}[--- de Morgan $\lor$(2)]\\
    \pline{\neg (p \lor q)}[\lande{4}]\\
    \pline{p \lor q}[\lori{3}]
  }
  \pline{\neg \neg ((p \land q) \lor (p \land r))}[\negi{5, 6}]\\
  \pline{(p \land q) \lor (p \land r)}[\nege{7}]\\
  \pline{(p \land (q \lor r)) \lif ((p \land q) \lor (p \land r))}[\lifi{1, 8}]
}
\end{document}

It gives this:

Is it possible to do the following:

Move the 9-th line out of the scope of the last hypothesis by removing the vertical line and shifting it a little to the left, but keeping the line number.
Allow to add the square marking the end of the proof below the last line (without line number).
Is it possible to reference the proof lines without hard-coding them into the proof?
So instead of \pline{p}[\lande{1}]\\ we would type:

\pline{(p \land (q \lor r))}[\ass]\label{ass-1}
...
\pline{p}[\lande{\ref{ass-1}}]\\


Make underscore characters _\text{в} and \text{и} a little bit bigger. Should I add \larger for them?


I thought you wanted not to have the horizontal lines but only the vertical ones?

I get `! Undefined control sequence.
 \negi
{5, 6}
l.56   }
?
! Undefined control sequence.
 \nege
{7}
l.56   }
?`

note that you really shouldn't ask 4 questions in a single question. (4) is really a different topic and doesn't have anything to do with the proof format itself, so I'd suggest asking that separately. (admittedly, this is partly because I don't know the answer.)

The code below changes the syntax of \mbproof to address the QED question. It also removes the  outer scope line if proving a tautology and enables cross-referencing.
It does not address question 4 because I don't know what is correct there. It also produces bad box warnings, but I'm not certain why. (But I think my original answer also probably produced them. I've not checked to see if the unmodified command does the same.)
\mbproof[<key-value list>]{<premise(s)>}{<proof>}

Arguments 2 and 3 are unchanged in terms of input, but the behaviour is adjusted if the first argument is empty. Argument 1 is optional. It uses key-value syntax and recognises the following keys:

to prove=<statement of inference or tautology>
centred=true|false or centred

flushleft is initially set; centred is equivalent to centred=true.


qed
no qed initial setting.

A QED symbol following a proof of this kind is typically entirely superfluous. There is a little more excuse for it if omitting the outer scope line. But that, imho, is a good reason not to omit the line. However, the book is definitive in such cases, so if the book omits the line and adds a symbol, that's what you're stuck with.
In addition to \mbproof[]{}{}, \mbproofset{<key-value list>} may be used to customise default values. The idea is to provide an interface which can be easily extended if necessary.
Cross-references aren't used consistently in the code below - just enough to test and demonstrate usage. I used the example from your previous question to check the code still does the right thing when there are premises.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/725536/
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lplfitch}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{\setcounter{equation}{0}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*\lif{\supset}
\renewcommand*\lifi[1]{\intro{\lif}, #1}
\renewcommand*\lande[1]{\elim{\land}, #1}
\newcommand*\negi[1]{\intro{\lnot}, #1}
\newcommand*\nege[1]{\elim{\lnot}, #1}
\renewcommand*\intro[1]{--- \formula{#1_\text{в}}}
\renewcommand*\elim[1]{--- \formula{#1_\text{и}}}
\newcommand*\ass{--- пос.}
\newcounter{plinecount}
\AddToHook{cmd/fitchprf/before}{%
  \def\cline#1{\relax}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_mbproof_to_prove_tl
\tl_new:N \l_mbproof_qed_tl
\tl_set_eq:NN \l_mbproof_qed_tl \c_empty_tl
\keys_define:nn { mbproof }
{
  centred .bool_set:N = \l_mbproof_centred_bool,
  centred .initial:n = false,
  centred .default:n = true,
  qed .code:n = {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_mbproof_qed_tl {
      \\
      \hspace*{.35em}
      \hspace*{\tabcolsep}
      \formula{\Box}
    }
  },
  no ~ qed .code:n = {
    \tl_set_eq:NN \l_mbproof_qed_tl \c_empty_tl
  },
  to ~ prove .code:n = {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_mbproof_to_prove_tl { \formula{ #1 } }
  },
  to ~ prove .initial:V = \c_empty_tl,
  to ~ prove .value_required:n = true,
}
\NewDocumentCommand \mbproofset { +m }
{
  \keys_set:nn {mbproof} { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \mbproof {o+m+m}{
  \group_begin:
    \setcounter{plinecount}{0}
    \IfValueT {#1}
    {%
      \keys_set:nn { mbproof } { #1 }
    }
    \bool_if:NTF \l_mbproof_centred_bool
    {
      \IfBlankTF {#2}
      {
        \begin{center}
          \l_mbproof_to_prove_tl\\\fitchprfunscoped{#3}
        \end{center}
      }{
        \begin{center}
          \l_mbproof_to_prove_tl\\\fitchprf{#2}{#3}
        \end{center}
      }
    }{%
      \IfBlankTF {#2}
      {
        \begin{flushleft}
          \l_mbproof_to_prove_tl\\\fitchprfunscoped{#3}
          \l_mbproof_qed_tl
        \end{flushleft}
      }{
        \begin{flushleft}
          \l_mbproof_to_prove_tl\\\fitchprf{#2}{#3}
          \l_mbproof_qed_tl
        \end{flushleft}
      }
    }
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\fitchprfunscoped}[1]{%
  \advance \fitchprfwidth by -\fitchsep%
  \advance \fitchprfwidth by .5pt%
  \hspace*{.35em}%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{p{0pt}@{}p{\fitchprfwidth}@{\hspace*{\fitchsep}}l}
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l@{}}{\ }\\[-2.35ex]
    #1 \\ \multicolumn{3}{@{}l@{}} \ \\[-2.35ex]
  \end{tabular}
  \advance \fitchprfwidth by \fitchsep%
}
\makeatletter
\def\pline{%
  \@ifnextchar[\@plinenum{%
    \@plinenum[%
      \refstepcounter{plinecount}\theplinecount.%
      \xdef\@currentlabel{\theplinecount}%
    ]%
  }%
}
\makeatother
% \addtolength{\fitchargwidth}{0pt}
% \addtolength{\fitchprfwidth}{0pt}
% \addtolength{\fitchctxwidth}{8pt}
\mbproofset{% defaults can be customised here and overridden for any proof
  centred=false,
  qed,
}
\begin{document}
\mbproof[to prove=\vdash (p \land (q \lor r)) \lif ((p \land q) \lor (p \land r))]
{}
{\subproof
  {
    \pline{(p \land (q \lor r))}[\ass]\label{ass:taut}
  }
  {
    \subproof{
      \pline{\neg ((p \land q) \lor (p \land r))}[\ass]\label{ass:taut-neg}
    }
    {
      \pline{p}[\lande{\ref{ass:taut}}]\label{ande-p}\\
      \pline{(\neg (p \lor q)) \land (\neg (p \lor r)}[--- de Morgan $\lor$(\ref{ass:taut-neg})]\label{de-morgan}\\
      \pline{\neg (p \lor q)}[\lande{\ref{de-morgan}}]\label{ande-p-or-q}\\
      \pline{p \lor q}[\lori{\ref{ande-p}}]\label{p-or-q}
    }
    \pline{\neg \neg ((p \land q) \lor (p \land r))}[\negi{\ref{ande-p-or-q}, \ref{p-or-q}}]\label{neg-neg}\\
    \pline{(p \land q) \lor (p \land r)}[\nege{\ref{neg-neg}}\label{no-neg}]
  }
  \pline{(p \land (q \lor r)) \lif ((p \land q) \lor (p \land r))}[\lifi{\ref{ass:taut}, \ref{no-neg}}]
}


\mbproof[to prove=p \lif r \vdash (p \land r) \lif r]
{%
  \pline{p \lif r}[\ass]
}{%
  \subproof{%
    \pline{p \land r}[\ass]\label{ass:p-r}
  }{%
    \pline{p}[\lande{2}]\\
    \pline{r}[\lande{2}]
  }
  \pline{(p \land r) \lif r}[\lifi{2--4}]
}

\mbproof[to prove=p \lif r \vdash (p \land r) \lif r,centred]
{%
  \pline{p \lif r}[\ass]
}{%
  \subproof{%
    \pline{p \land r}[\ass]\label{ass:p-r2}
  }{%
    \pline{p}[\lande{\ref{ass:p-r2}}]\\
    \pline{r}[\lande{2}]
  }
  \pline{(p \land r) \lif r}[\lifi{2--4}]
}

\ref{ass:p-r2} is an assumption in a proof.
\end{document}


